# How to Perl Get Meta-Content

Tags: html, perl

This HTML Info

```
<title>Private Video Link 16:9</title>
<meta content="index,follow,noarchive" name="robots">
<meta content="movie" property="og:type">
<meta content="application/x-shockwave-flash" property="og:video:type">
<meta content="2014_PIW_8102_83462_ocindoor" property="og:title">
<meta content="640" property="og:video:width">
```

it posible if i'am want print this line only

```
<meta content="2014_PIW_8102_83462_ocindoor" property="og:title">
```

This My code

```
$URL = get ("www.google.com");
$Head = HTML::HeadParser->new;
$Head->parse("$URL");
print $Head->header('Title');
```

am used HeadParser

or use regular expression

thank you

Answer (score 0):

HTML::HeadParser is not fully featured to do what you want. (On a cursory glance).

You can just use regex on the HTML yourself.

```
if ($URL =~ /meta content="\w+" property="og:title"/) {
     print $_;
}
```

http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/perl/regexp.html learning more is an exercise to you.

Answer (score 0):

[HTML::TreeBuilder](http://lwp.interglacial.com/ch09_03.htm) will make you happier. The linked article should give you a good idea of how to loop over similar tree entries.